# Sharing strings and files over wifiDirect in android app

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I am trying to share internal app data between two phones on which the app is installed. I tried following android documentation. I am able to connect to the device successfully but couldn't get success in transferring data. I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002303/data-transfer-between-two-wifi-devices) answer too, but it didn't work for me.

There is a demo app from google where a file is shared from client-side to server-side but I want data to be transferred both ways.

Can anyone help please.

Comment: Looking for same answer. If you manage to solve, please post the answer.

Comment: Succeeded in transferring strings from both sides. Will try out transferring files tomorrow.